# Having trouble converting a decimal into a binary in C. No output

Tags: c, radix

Normally this would be easy, but I just started learning C. I'm using visual studio 2017 community and right now I don't seem to be able to use watches. When I run the program it outputs nothing. What did I do wrong?

```
//20_10_17
//Crehul Vlad
//Base conversion: Decimal into Binary
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int k=0, i, r, nr, c, N[64];
    printf("Decimal Nr: "); scanf("%d", &nr);
    c = nr;
    while (nr % 2 != 0) {
        r = c % 2;
        c = c / 2;
        N[k] = r; k++;
    }
    for (i = k; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%d ", N[i]);
    }

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void main` is wrong. `main` should return `int`.

Comment: forgot to flush the output.

Comment: `_getch` is not a standard function.

Comment: @melpomene Didn't change anything but thanks for the headsup.

Comment: `while (nr % 2 != 0)` =====> `nr` is not changed. This could be an answer but the code is so poor it would become a tutorial.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't even know what that is. I tried to add 'fflush( stdout );' but didn't change anything

Comment: If you can use watches, you should be able to step. Go through, single-stepping, and work out why you put in 'c = nr;', mutated c but then looped on nr:(

Comment: @WeatherVane Now I feel dumb. Thanks for the help. and it was supposed to be `c / 2` not `c % 2` . Thanks that solved it!

Comment: @at some point `N[k] = r; k++;` is pout of bounds

Comment: @MartinJames Problem is I can't seem to find the option to add watches. New to this IDE and can't find a tutorial for the 2017 version.

Comment: The way how your program is, if you type `100` is ok, but if you type for example `5´ is segfault. Now think why.

Comment: Just hold down F11 and watch the line cursor flopping endlessly round your while loop on KB auto-repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int k=0, i, r, nr, c, N[64];
    printf("Decimal Nr: "); scanf("%d", &nr);
    c = nr;
    if(nr==0)
      printf("0");
    else{
    while (nr) {
        r = nr % 2;
        nr = nr / 2;
        N[k] = r; k++;
      }
    }
    // original number in variable c
    for (i = k-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d ", N[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just try to understand what the algorithm does. And be careful when you code terminating conditions.

Comment: Corner case when `nr` is `0` will then use uninitialised variables.

Comment: You modified the whole program and now works different and still wrong

Comment: @WeatherVane.: Edited.

Comment: `print 0;` really?

Comment: Funny that OP accepted your Answer.  Anyway do you know when you type `100` ? test it.

Comment: @Michi.: Just tried to give an idea...I use mobile..too lazy to add brackets

Comment: @coderredoc Just type `100`

Comment: @Michi.: It is converting to binary by considering every bit of it. Modular arithemtic is getting th ebits.

Comment: You do not understand me. [this is the result of your code](https://pastebin.com/raw/fvk3eN5U). I hope you understand now.

Comment: I managed to fix it. I forgot I used `c` instead of `nr`

Comment: @VladCrehul Good spot

Comment: @Michi.: I directly used `nr` for conversion..there is nothing wrong.

Comment: @VladCrehul `printf("Decimal number: %d converted into binary is: "` you forgot something.

Comment: @Michi.: OP''s original code never used `nr`. and if it is neded it is already copied in `c`.

Comment: @Michi.: still waiting for clarification.

Comment: @coderredoc Please show a working code based of OP code together with your modification.

Comment: @Michi.: Edited...the details like printing can be done anyway OP likes...the answers are ready in the array `N[]` and variable `c` conmtains original decimal number

Comment: @coderredoc This is another reason why [One should never use IDEONE](https://ideone.com/85CmJX)

Comment: @Michi.: The code is giving correct result when you give proper input...

Comment: @coderredoc I know, but not on IDEONE. Try your code and type 100 :))

Comment: @Michi.: Fork the code and then click input..write 100..and then click `Run`..and chekc the result in Output.

Comment: @coderredoc Your code is fine. [we are just](https://imgur.com/zWLBIQo) not understand each other. [I give up](https://imgur.com/nrKZXyB).

Comment: @Michi.:I just am trying to say that...when you fork it and run it...it shows the correct output. But initally it shows some absurd output..which can be confusing. I get your point. But yes you have to ignore the initial glitch... :)